# Code not working anymore in the latest python version

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
cmd_login =   '534d4100000402a000000001003a001060650ea0ffffffffffff00017800%s00010000000004800c04fdff07000000840300004c20cb5100000000%s00000000' % (struct.pack('<I', src_serial).encode('hex'), get_encoded_pw(user_pw))
```

written for python 2.7.

I don't find how to change this, to get it working in python 3.9.  I get the error: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'.

Answer (score 0):

The `struct.pack` function returns a `bytes` object. If you want to convert that to a hex string it has direct support for that using its `hex()` method.

```py
data = b"abcde"
data.hex()
```

Produces:

```
'6162636465'
```